# Sheer UI in Sitecore 8.2

Tags: sheer-ui

I am porting a Sheer UI dialog from a Sitecore 8 solution into a Sitecore 8.2 one (which also has SXA installed).

Has anything changed in Sitecore 8.2 regarding Sheer UI? (I know I *should* be using SPEAK UI, but I want to get this working in Sheer UI before I start any conversion).

My solution has the following:

```
/sitecore/layout/Layouts/Tools/My Dialog Layout
```

This is the layout which references the Sheer UI xml control. The `Control` field is set to the file name of the Xml control (minus the file extension) and the `Path` is blank.

```
/sitecore/content/Applications/My Dialog
```

This is the application (dialog) itself. This item references "My Dialog Layout" in the presentation details.

```
/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Programs/My Dialog
```

This is the start menu shortcut. The `Application` field is set to link to `/sitecore/content/Applications/My Dialog`. **This does not appear in the start menu for some reason. I have also tried moving this under `/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start menu/Right/Development Tools` which also does not work.**

```
/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/Tools/My Dialog
```

This uses the LaunchPad-Button template and has the `Link` field set to `/sitecore/shell/Applications/My Dialog.aspx?sc_bw=1`. This button *does* appear in the Launch Pad page, but shows a blank page when rendered. No errors.

Comment: did you go through this link if you trying to build dialog in xEditor. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/359871

Comment: I'm only displaying the dialog from the start menu and the launchpad, not the experience editor, so I don't think that applies. I could be wrong though...

Comment: Have you considered simply rewriting the dialog using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions? It's current based on Sheer UI but offers a method of rapid prototyping and development. SXA requires SPE so you already have met the necessary prerequisite.

Comment: This is an interesting option, but I don't really have time for any kind of re-write at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a non-issue.**

During porting, I renamed the Sheer UI XML control

It seems that the xml element beneath the root `<control>` element must match the `Control` field of the layout item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <control xmlns:def="Definition" xmlns="http://schemas.sitecore.net/Visual-Studio-Intellisense">
    <SiteCopier> <!-- this element must match the "Control" field of the item under /sitecore/layout/Layouts/Tools/ -->
      <FormPage>
        <CodeBeside Type="Blah.blah, Blah" />
```